# How can I embed resources in output of Web Deployment Project?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, embedded-resource, web-deployment-project

I have an asp.net project that holds my user controls within a Web Deployment project.
I use Web Deployment project to output a single dll file, so I can use controls easily in other projects.
So how can I embed resourses (like js, image,... files) into this single dll?

Answer (score 0):

Change the build action to embedded resource for the files.

Comment: As I mentioned before this is a asp.net web project so I haven't such property for files